# how to include vendor autoload in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am a newbie in CodeIgniter, I just wanted to ask if how can I include a vendor/autoload file in CodeIgniter? I haven't tried any solution yet, so maybe someone can help me with this?

Comment: where you want to include autoload? have you really tried anything?

Comment: require_once APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: What I did is, I put vendor/autoload.php on the third party folder, then I created a class in the library folder which calls the files. The class contains something like this : 

<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class RandomClass {

  public function __construct()
    {
        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/vendor/autoload.php';
    }

}
?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change composer autoload settings **false** to **true** in your config file.

`$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;`

2. Add this line to your **index.php** file.

`include_once './vendor/autoload.php';`

3. Create library file as **VendorLibrary.php** in the library folder.

Code

```
use Vendor\ClassName;

class ClassNameLibrary {

    public $class;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->class = new ClassName();
    } 

    public function clear($data)
    {
        return $this->class->clean($data);
    }
}
```

4.Load library in your controller like this.

Code

```
class HomeController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->library('classnamelibrary');
    } 

    public function index()
    {
        $clean = $this->classnamelibrary->clear($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already solved this problem but still, thank you for your time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't include it in **autoload.php** as it will always loaded no matter if you use the library function of not, Just make a `helper` and at the top `include_once 'FCPATH."vendor/autoload.php"';`

here `FCPATH` is the folder location of your CI APP. it's a constant declared in **index.php**.

now call the helper function when you need that particular function and doing this won't require you to touch **config.php** in any ways.

Hope this helps

Comment: I already solved this problem but still, thank you for your time to answer.